# Why aren't checkbox input change events composed?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm finding that `change` events generated by an `<input type="checkbox">` have `composed` set to `false` (at least on Chrome 80).

The `Event.composed` flag determines if events propagate across shadow DOM boundaries. The documentation for `Event.composed` on Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composed) states:

> All UA-dispatched UI events are composed
>   (click/touch/mouseover/copy/paste, etc.).

So, is `composed = false` the expected behavior for input change events?

Is this documented in a spec (I've tried unsuccessfully to find it)?

If this is the expected behavior, what is the rationale for `composed = false` for `change`, but `composed = true` for, say `click`?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 2):

The following has been taken verbatim from this article: [Shadow DOM v1: Self-Contained Web Components  |  Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#events)

---

> The Shadow DOM event model
>   --- When an event bubbles up from shadow DOM it's target is adjusted to maintain the encapsulation that shadow DOM provides. That is,
>   events are re-targeted to look like they've come from the component
>   rather than internal elements within your shadow DOM. Some events do
>   not even propagate out of shadow DOM.
>
> The events that do cross the shadow boundary are:
>
> - Focus Events: blur, focus, focusin, focusout
> - Mouse Events: click, dblclick, mousedown, mouseenter, mousemove, etc.
> - Wheel Events: wheel
> - Input Events: beforeinput, input
> - Keyboard Events: keydown, keyup
> - Composition Events: compositionstart, compositionupdate, compositionend
> - DragEvent: dragstart, drag, dragend, drop, etc.

---

As for specs, the change event is not an instance of InputEvent or UIEvent: https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#events-inputevents. It is an instance of Event.

As for rationale as to why it doesn't bubble out of a Shadow DOM, I'm afraid I can't offer much for certain. All I can say is that the change event does not refer directly to the user action, like the event 'input' does, but rather refers to the changing of the value of the HTMLElement. I imagine only events considered user actions should bubble out.

---

**Edit to include further references:**

Here is the discussion surrounding the rationale for the change to the spec: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/513

Comment: Thanks. Re:spec, you say "the change event is not an instance of InputEvent or UIEvent", but does a spec ever say that only `InputEvents` and `UIEvents` bubble out of Shadow Dom? Re:rationale, you say "only events considered user actions should bubble out", but in [HTML Living Standard 4.10.5.5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#common-input-element-events), `change` and `input` events have the same status in regard to user actions, differing only in when they occur: on modification (`input`) or commit (`change`). Not trying to be argumentative, just trying to understand...

Comment: No problem, happy for the discussion. My interpretation of the following in the spec you referenced: "The input event fires whenever the user has modified the data of the control. The change event fires when the value is committed" is as I said; the input event is consider a user action / UI event, while the change event is not. I also just made an edit to the answer which includes the rationale behind the change to the spec I referenced (the addition of the composed property, and the events for which it should be true).

Comment: I see this issue has been raised too, don't know if it's a coincidence or not :) https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5453. There seems to be some confusion over what browsers should be implementing. If it helps with your use case, don't forget that it is possible to retarget the event manually yourself. If the mode of the attached shadow is closed, it will be more difficult but not impossible.